# How to leverage Spark features in a custom algorithm?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark

I developed an algorithm in Java which treats large data set.Using Eclipse. Now I want to take advantages  of Spark Apache . How can I run this algorithm under Spark environment? what tools I need and how can I connect Eclipse to Spark? 
By the way, I followed a course i Edx web site and installed Spark as a local server on VirtualBox and Vagrant. But I don't know how can I connect it to My algorithm that I developed it by Eclipse.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the "spark-submit" command to run in the spark cluster.

```
./bin/spark-submit --class <main-class> --master <master-url>  <application-jar>      [application-arguments]
```